# Node copyfile hangs inside docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on this node function.

```
  #copyInCommonFile(tmpDir, commonfile) {
    var newfile = path.join(tmpDir, commonfile.fileName);
    
    try {
      fs.copyFileSync(commonfile.commonFilePath, newfile);
      this.logger.info('Copied file from : ' + commonfile.commonFilePath + ' to ' + newfile);
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  }
```

My problem is that no matter what I do, this method hangs with no error.  I've tried the sync and async methods.  This is supposed to copy a file from one directory inside the docker container to another directory.  The app just sits there and hangs on the method until it is killed.

The result is that it does create an empty file in the new location.

I have been at this all morning, im out of ideas.  do you fine folks have any?

Comment: does it work locally?

Comment: at this point in the game, everything is local.  If you are asking if i can replicate it outside of a container, no.  none of this code is capable of being run outside a container.

Comment: Are you saying its not working locally or its too difficult to run locally due to depdencies? Because if its not working locally, then its not a problem with docker but with the code itself. Would be worth finding that out.

Comment: because of dependencies, i can't run it outside a container.

Comment: I've had a similar issue. Can you ensure that the source file is complete and fully written before attempting to copy it?